# Where does this "Load more" action go and where do I deal with the logic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, design-patterns, model-view-controller, controller

I have an app displaying events in lists. The events can be displayed either for the wholde community or by organizer.

```
class CommunitiesController < ApplicationController
    def show
        @community = Community.find(params[:id])
    end
end

class OrganizersController < ApplicationController
    def show
        @organizer = Organizer.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

show.html.erb:

```
<%= @community.events.limit(15).each do |event| %>
...
<% end %>
```

I want to implement a "Load more events"-button at the end of the list, that loads the sequential events via an ajax-call in batches of 15.

**So, for the sake of good MVC-design, I have the following questions:**

Where should this additional action (the request for more events) go, in Communities/Organizers or in Events? Or even somewhere else as it breaks REST?

And in what model (or controller?) should the logic, calculating where in the sequence we are and what to send, go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feels like controller logic. I would have the controller extract the appropriate chunk of 15 records based on some index specified by a `:page` parameter, then the view just displays whatever it is passed, e.g.

```
page_size = 15 # configure this somewhere
...
@events = @community.events.offset(page_size * (params[:page] || 0).to_i).limit(page_size)
```

Then in your view...

```
<%= @events.each do |event| %>
...
<% end %>
```

There are other ways to pass the `@events` into your view, and probably better approaches to paging, but this should be the basic idea.